# Archiva Jenkins Communication via https

Tags: ssl, https, jenkins, archiva

I try to build the communication between Archiva and Jenkins via https protokol, but i receive following mistakes:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata ...:3.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to archiva.snapshots (https://localhost:8443/archiva/repository/snapshots/): **peer not authenticated**
org.sonatype.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata ...:3.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to archiva.snapshots (https://localhost:8443/archiva/repository/snapshots/): peer not authenticated
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:930)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:920)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: peer not authenticated
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:892)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.ConfigurableSSLSocketFactoryDecorator.connectSocket(ConfigurableSSLSocketFactoryDecorator.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:746)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:886)
    ... 8 more
```

p.s.
I generated Security Keys, and configured Jetty.
I can connect to Archiva with `https protokol: https://lokal:8443/archiva/browse/`... to my repository.

But if i change in **pom.xml** protokol **`from http://lokal:8080`** to  **`https://lokal:8443*`* i can't build and i receive mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your archiva server has probably an invalid (self-signed) SSL certificate. Your browser probably displays a warning, but still shows you the content. Maven code will not.

Here are some tips to workaround the problem: http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Maven+with+untrusted+SSL+Certificates

Depending on your needs, you might want to purchase an SSL certificate.